# Installing Ruby on Rails on Windows via CYGWIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin

I am attempting to follow instructions on this page:

http://www.agilereasoning.com/2011/05/25/ruby-on-rails-on-windows-7-using-cygwin/

I have been trying to install Rails with varying success first using the railsinstaller and I encounter difficulties like no vim and I couldn't copy and paste from the Windows command prompt so I install CYGWIN. It didn't download the files correctly so I downloaded them manually and some were hard to locate. I couldn't find the final package as a .tar file so I downloaded libxslt-devel-1.1.20-1.i386.rpm.

> ### Right click the Cygwin shortcut and choose edit from the menu. Change the contents to >match:
>
> 1 @echo off
>   2  C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt -sr -sl 1500 -e C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i

Do I have to put this as a command to run on the executable or inside the cygwin commmand prompt? When I try to do that I get this:

> ### -bash: 'command': command not found

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things wrong here.

- You can copy/paste the command prompt with Edit->Mark or Edit->Paste
- libxslt-devel-1.1.20-1.i386.rpm is a linux file.
- C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt - why are you mesing around with rxvt?

I recommend you install the [rubyinstaller + devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and then do gem install rails. However don't expect to be happy with rails' performance on windows.

Comment: Someone said I should use CYGWIN. I'm not really excited about having a dual boot. On the website it mentions to run that command.

Comment: Cygwin runs on windows. There's no dual boot involved.

Comment: No. I want to use Cygwin so I don't have to install Linux. I don't really like using the Windows command prompt. I have tried using the rails installer and it didn't work out.

Comment: Well I'm using cygwin with ruby installed the way I described and it works fine for me.

Comment: Okay, I will attempt rubyinstaller + devkit.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails on Windows via CYGWIN
Try:

Install [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com)

[Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org),

and Cygwin (or PuTTy, I am using Cygwin).

With this set, open Cygwin, go to your project folder, run `vagrant init <box>` (my box is [hashicorp/precise64 - see others](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search))
(you may also want to cfg your [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/jacksonpires/403ac7e61dfd70e302b1da281decbe15)?). 
 All set, Run: `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` 
Now you have a virtual machine (Ubuntu) running, and you can install rvm (recommended... so you can have different versions of Ruby), or go directly with ruby, rails, etc.. (`sudo apt-get ruby -v x.x.x`,etc) 

- Vagrant "creates and configures lightweight, reproducible, and portable development environments".

 - Cygwin helps with ssh issues, etc...

 - Virtual Box manages the machine (Ubuntu, or other OS)

With this set, I have no problem at all running Ruby (on Rails) with Windows.